# Cannot read proprety "dataSource" of null

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming

I feel like this should be pretty straightforward but I'm losing my mind trying to create a basic list in react. I tried the minimalistic sample code on react-native but it yields the error message. Cannot read property "dataSource" of null, even thought the dataSource is being created in the getInitialState.

Here it is

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead of `getInitialState`:

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props);
  var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
  this.state = {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row1', 'row2'])
  };
}
```

This is because you're using ES2016 classes: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes

Comment: Thanks it works, however I'm still not seeing a list view in my simulator

Comment: This can be due to other things. Can't help if you don't post your full source code.

Comment: Sorry was working. Here is the repo. 

https://github.com/EngineerDiab/golf-Stats-ReactNative/tree/master/Golf

I'm using react-router-flux for my tab view and now I'm trying to get a list view within the tabs. Any help would be appreciated